# Redefine class of an object in R

Tags: r, class, object, transform, coercion

My object has the class "character". g.g.

```
x <- rep(TRUE,4)
x <- replace(x,3,FALSE)
```

I now would like to coerce/transform this into a being a *logical* class. How do I change the class of x?

Comment: With the code you have here, it is already a logical vector. The result of `class(x)`. is `logical`.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you mean in your example:

```
x <- rep("TRUE", 4) 
x <- replace(x, 3, "FALSE")
class(x)
# "character"
```

In which case try:

```
y <- as.logical(x)
class(y)
# "logical"
```

Comment: yes, you are right. Otherwise the example does not work as the problem does not occur in the first place. Thanks a lot for your help